# Create array of python class objects from objects in json file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, class

I have a json file like this ('./serverApi/comuni.json' is the json file)

```
[
  {
    "nome": "Abano Terme",
    "codice": "028001",
    "zona": { "codice": "2", "nome": "Nord-est" },
    "regione": { "codice": "05", "nome": "Veneto" },
    "provincia": { "codice": "028", "nome": "Padova" },
    "sigla": "PD",
    "codiceCatastale": "A001",
    "cap": ["35031"],
    "popolazione": 19349
  },
  {
    "nome": "Abbadia Cerreto",
    "codice": "098001",
    "zona": { "codice": "1", "nome": "Nord-ovest" },
    "regione": { "codice": "03", "nome": "Lombardia" },
    "provincia": { "codice": "098", "nome": "Lodi" },
    "sigla": "LO",
    "codiceCatastale": "A004",
    "cap": ["26834"],
    "popolazione": 297
  }, {and so on}
]
```

I need to turn it into an object array with some of the properties through a python class. This is my attempt, something is clearly missing, hope you can help

```
import json

class Comune:
    def __init__(self, nome: str, provincia: object, regione: str): 
            self.nome = nome
            self.provincia = provincia
            self.regione = regione

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps({
          "nome":self.nome,
          "provincia":self.provincia,
          "regione":self.regione
        })
    
    @staticmethod
    def comuni_decoder(obj):
        return Comune(obj['nome'], obj['provincia']['nome'], obj['regione']['nome'])

with open('./serverApi/comuni.json', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as c:
    comuni_pre = json.load(c, object_hook=Comune.comuni_decoder)
    #comuni_post = [vars(c) for c in comuni_pre]

#print(comuni_pre)
```

I keep receiving this error:

```
return Comune(obj['nome'], obj['provincia']['nome'], obj['regione']['nome'])
                               ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'provincia'
```

EDIT: I've found a solution but I don't know if it is the best possibile

```
import json

class Comune:
    def __init__(self, nome, provincia, regione):
        self.nome = nome
        self.provincia = provincia
        self.regione = regione
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps({"nome":self.nome, "provincia":self.provincia, "regione":self.regione}, indent=4)

with open("./serverApi/comuni.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

comuni = []

for comune in data:
    nome = comune["nome"]
    provincia = comune["provincia"]["nome"]
    regione = comune["regione"]["nome"]
    comuni.append(Comune(nome, provincia, regione))
    
comuni2 = [vars(c) for c in comuni]
```

"comuni2" is what I need to be able to work properly with a list, is there a better solution?

Comment: " into an object array " just a terminology point: that is a *list* not an array. And *every list is an "object list"*. **everything** is an object in Python, i.e. **everything** is an instance of a class. A "class object" means *the actual class itself* (classes are *also objects*!).

Comment: Anyway, just `json.load` it using the default object mapping, then do something like `[Comune.comuni_decoder(record) for record in communi_pre]`